# Determining offset relative to parent when using overflow: auto (Straight JS)

Tags: javascript, dom

I have code where there is a div which is scrollable. I find the offset using the following...

```
function elementInViewport(el, scrollArea) {
  var top = el.getBoundingClientRect().top - 90; //Here is the issue
  console.log(scrollArea.scrollTop);
  return ( 0 < top <= 10);
}
```

I appear to have to subtract 90px because I have a 90px header before the scroll-able area. This seems to be based on page location and not relative to the scroll-area div. For example, if I look at the first child div `el.getBoundingClientRect().top` returns 90 while `scrollArea.scrollTop` returns 0.

The HTML looks like this...

```
<div>
  <div class="header">...</div> // Hardcoded to 90px height
  <div id="#scroll-area" class="body"> //Height calc(100% - 90px)
    <div id="area1"></div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about posting an inline snippet?

Comment: Here is a snippet http://plnkr.co/edit/dDghx0g817LiskUnVLMA?p=preview